# How to disable Git's MSWord integration with `*.dot` files?

Tags: git, ms-word, file-extension

I made a file with a `*.dot` extension.
It's a text file, nothing to do with MS Word.

When I try to use `git diff` I get this error:

```
C:\Users\Christopher\Source\Repos\time>git diff dependencies/dependencies.dot
warning: CRLF will be replaced by LF in dependencies/dependencies.dot.
The file will have its original line endings in your working directory
C:\Users\CHRIST~1\AppData\Local\Temp/fX3Ut1_dependencies.dot is not a Word Document.
dependencies/dependencies.dot is not a Word Document.
```

Apparently Git thinks it's a Word Document.
I'm surprised -- I thought Git treated all files as text.

Can I configure Git to treat this like a regular text file?

The problem is on my machine (running Windows 10): when the file is on GitHub I can properly see its diffs.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My `C:\Program Files\Git\etc\gitattributes` file contains an entry like this:

```
*.dot   diff=astextplain
*.DOT   diff=astextplain
```

`astextplain` is a script in `C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin\` which invokes `C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin\antiword.exe`.

`astextplain` also does something similar for Open Document, PDF, and RTF files.

So a solution seems to be a file named `.gitattributes` (e.g. in the project or directory which contains the *.dot file) with content as follows:

```
*.dot   diff=
*.DOT   diff=
```

Comment: Since the settings are system-specific and not important for the project, it is best to place the antidotes (pun intended) in `.git/info/attributes`, not `.gitattributes`.